# NoSuchMethodError: org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings.settingsBuilder()

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm running into this exception on startup with spring-boot + spring-data-elasticsearch when connecting to a remote elastic search server :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.Client]: Factory method 'elasticsearchClient' threw exception; 
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings.settingsBuilder()Lorg/elasticsearch/common/settings/Settings$Builder;
```

My relevant gradle deps are :

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-parent', version: '1.5.8.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-elasticsearch', version: '3.0.1.RELEASE'
compile('org.elasticsearch.client:transport:5.5.0')
```

Elasticsearch 5.5.0 is the server version.   I have experienced the same problem with 5.2.2 and 5.6.4.   I have also tried using the latest spring-boot milestone 2.0.0.M6.

The relevant code is below, which closely follows the elasticsearch [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/5.5/transport-client.html) :

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories("com.me.repository.elasticsearch")
public class ElasticSearchConfig {
@Value("${spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name:elasticsearch}")
    private String clusterName;
    @Value("${spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes:es-server:9300}")
    private String clusterNodes;
    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate() throws UnknownHostException {
        String server = clusterNodes.split(":")[0];
        Integer port = Integer.parseInt(clusterNodes.split(":")[1]);
        Settings settings = Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", clusterName).build();
        TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(server), port));
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client);
    }
}
```

I see mention of this issue on the ElasticSearch forums [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/cant-create-transport-client-for-elasticsearch-5-2-2/79690), and it is described an issue with Spring referencing the deprecated settingsBuilder() method, but no solution provided.    Per the [docs](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch), I am using the correct version of spring-data-elasticsearch, given my ElasticSearch version.

Interestingly, I see a connection established to the elasticsearch server when spring starts up, before the exception is thrown.